# Connection to Azure blob storage does not work when running a Unit test

Tags: azure, resharper, azure-blob-storage

I wrote a very simple program to test to upload files to an Azure Blob Storage and I also wrote a unit test for it.
The problem for me is that the code running the console app and the unit test are exactly the same, but the unit test are trying to connect to localhost (they have the same connectionstring).

The code that produce the error is this:

```
public class AzureFileUploadRepository : IFileUploadRepository
{
    public string UploadFile(byte[] file, Guid? fileName = null)
    {
        var container = this.GetContainer();

        if (!fileName.HasValue)
        {
            fileName = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName.ToString());
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(file))
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memStream);
        }

        return fileName.Value.ToString();
    }

    private CloudBlobContainer GetContainer()
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        return container;
    }
}
```

As you see it is very basic code and it works when running it from the console app but when running a unit test with Resharper I get this error:
[image]
It seems like Resharper are using a proxy or something but I can not find out where to fix this.

Anyone got a clue?

If you like to test yourself, the source code is here (You need to replace [StorageConString] with your own connectionstring to your own blob storage
https://github.com/hesta96/BlobTester

Comment: In your unit tests, are you connecting to storage emulator or a cloud storage account?

Comment: Do you use the same configuration file for both Console Application and Unit Test?

Comment: I am using the exact same connectionstring on both solutions and when a friend tried the code out both test and console app worked

Comment: If you like to test yourself, the source code is here (You need to replace [StorageConString] with your own connectionstring to your own blob storage
https://github.com/hesta96/BlobTester

Comment: Can you write a test that asserts the string being read from the config file? It would seem that ReSharper isn't looking at the correct config file. Also, are you running multiple test projects at the same time - does it fail if you run just that one test?

Comment: @citizenmatt I just did that and that test came out green so Resharper are looking at the correct connectionstring but is somehow set to use this local Azure test service

Comment: Try checking the "Use Separate AppDomain for each assembly with tests" option in ReSharper Options &rarr; Unit Testing. If you're running multiple projects with tests, ReSharper will try to optimise by running them in the same AppDomain, but that means it might pick up the wrong app.config

Comment: @citizenmatt tried it with no luck. I also added a MS test project to the solution and that test was execution with ok result. This is a very simple solution (see the code on github)

Answer (score 0):

I run the unit test with Resharper that test came out green.But when I set the Web proxy then get the same issue with you.Please have a try to edit the Web proxy and make sure that the box labeled “Use a proxy server for your LAN.” are unchecked. Please Refer to  [how to turn off the IE Proxy server](http://www.ehow.com/how_6812872_turn-proxy-server-settings-ie.html). Hope it can help you.

[ReSharper]->[Options]->[Web Proxy Settings]->[Edit]

[image: Resharper]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried that with no luck. Must be something strange on just my machine, I will update to latest version of R#, lets hope it will fix this